# ModalPopup div not displaying

Tags: asp.net, listview, html, popup, modal-dialog

I have a ModalPopup window in my asp.net application, that I want to display when a Listview control item is clicked.

```
 <div id="ModalPopup" style="visibility:hidden" runat="server">
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10002; background-color: Gray; filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7;">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <table style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10003;">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <div style="color: Black; font-weight: bolder; background-color: White; padding: 15px; width: 200px;">
          <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />...Processing....
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

However, in my `RadListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event, my code is: `ModalPopup.Attributes.Add("style", "visibility:visible");`  but the modal popup does not display.

How can I display it when a ListView item is selected?

Comment: Using a postback for this will drain your application of anything resembling usability. Do yourself a favor and jquery/javascript the modal popup.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already defined your `ModalPopup` div as a server control (e.g. `runat=server`) ***and*** you're trying to decide if to show it or not *in codebehind* - just use the `Visible` property...

```
 <div id="ModalPopup" Visible="false" runat="server">
   ....
 </div>
```

And in your `RadListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` event in code behind just change Visible to true:

```
protected void RadListView1_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    ModalPopup.Visible = true;
}
```

and if you insist on changing the visibility attribute itself, you can use **[RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)** like this:

```
protected void RadListView1_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", "document.getElementById('" + ModalPopup.ClientID + "').style.visibility = 'visible';", true);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem likely, please post your new updated code, including relevant codebehind in your original question...